# Appointment in one year

Tags: expressions

I should find appropriate English phrase/expression for very late(?) appointment.

Let's take a situation when someone should wait until the surgery operation for a one or too years just because there are a lot of similar patients "before" him in awaiting line.

What is the phrase for this situation?

"Long/late/??? appointment/line/?"

Comment: why do you (and so many others) assume that there's a single word for everything, however convoluted and specific?

Comment: You can say "the appointment is distant". In the securities world, when a derivative has a particularly (time) distant expiration or maturity, we say it is "*long dated*" (or, for fixed income products, "*out the curve*").

Comment: @jwenting: people assume so because so often there is. Unfortunately, it's not true. There's a history here of [reasonable annoyance with SWRs](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/reconsidering-the-single-word-request)

Comment: @Mitch yes, there's a lot of words. But it still irks me that people seem to think there should be a single word for everything and anything, and then not show any effort in actually finding it themselves. It's probably half the questions here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, you want to know what the term is for an appointment that is set for a long time in the future. As far as I know, there's no set way to say what you want to say. However, you could say that there is "a long waiting time" for the appointment, or perhaps you could call it a "delayed appointment".

Answer (score 0):

*Your appointment will be in one year's time.* Meaning, one year from this date.

*Your appointment will be next year.

Your appointment will be sometime in the next two years.

Your appointment won't be until sometime in the next three years.*
 These three are all saying the same thing, just change the time amount accordingly.

Comment: I am looking for adjective/expression/phrase for the situation, not just to say that the appointment is in one year. Something like "this appointment is LONG etc"

Comment: _The appointment is a long way off._ meaning that the appointment for whatever isn't going to happen for quite some time. If that isn't what you want then I give up. :)

Answer (score 0):

In healthcare, the noun phrase that we use in this situation is "wait time," as in:

**Patients are concerned about long wait times for elective surgery.**

**I am continually frustrated by the long wait times for appointments with my GP.**

**The hospital has invested a lot of resources into reducing wait times for patients.**

**I'm sorry, but we're currently dealing with long wait times for that procedure.**